# Ssh hang after execute some command

Tags: ssh

I run some command through ssh: ssh root@remote "SOME_COMMAND", but the ssh does not return after command done. It just hang there.

The client side ssh log:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
```

And the log from sshd:

```
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988431+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 12 len 0
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988518+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: read failed
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988559+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 12 efd 14 [read])
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988600+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988635+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: ibuf_empty delayed efd 14/(0)
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988671+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: notify_done: reading
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988706+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988740+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug1: session_by_pid: pid 26284
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988775+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 26284
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988813+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: request exit-status confirm 0
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988849+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug3: send packet: type 98
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988882+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988916+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: write failed
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988950+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i1 o0 sock -1 wfd 11 efd 14 [read])
2024-03-03T03:24:34.988984+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: send eow
2024-03-03T03:24:34.989022+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug3: send packet: type 98
2024-03-03T03:24:34.989055+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
2024-03-03T03:24:34.989089+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: ibuf_empty delayed efd 14/(0)
2024-03-03T03:24:34.989123+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug2: channel 0: ibuf_empty delayed efd 14/(0)
2024-03-03T03:24:38.727125+00:00 self sshd[3758]: debug3: receive packet: type 2
2024-03-03T03:24:38.727213+00:00 self sshd[3758]: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
2024-03-03T03:25:05.790042+00:00 self sshd[30063]: debug3: receive packet: type 2
2024-03-03T03:25:05.790129+00:00 self sshd[30063]: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
2024-03-03T03:25:34.218472+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug3: receive packet: type 80
2024-03-03T03:25:34.218559+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
2024-03-03T03:25:34.218607+00:00 self sshd[26283]: debug3: send packet: type 82
```

The server log "ibuf_empty delayed efd" looks suspicious. But I didn't find any useful info on internet.

Comment: Are you sure command is done? Can you verify it on the remote system?

Comment: Yes. The command is done. I double check it with pstree.

Comment: Why pstree? Use ps. And did you check it had run in the first place? What ssh server? what ssh client? What does netstat at both ends tell you? Did you test with a different server? a different client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command ssh executed is a script. It turns out it contains some commands runs in background:

```
CMD_Background &
```

I changed them to:

```
CMD_Background 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

By redirecting STD IO, the hang was fixed. Looks like ssh refuses to lose any data from/to the background job.